# Vue 3 watch doesn’t work if I watch a destructured prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to watch a prop in Vue 3 but it is strange that when I destructure it then the watcher doesn't work. But without destructuring it works as expected. What am I missing here?

*P.S. I am using Vue 3 + Vite*

**This is not working**

```
export default {
    props: {
        modelValue: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },

    setup({ modelValue }, context)
    {
        watch(() => modelValue, (newValue, oldValue) => {
            console.log(newValue)
        })
    },
}
```

But if I don’t destructure it then **it works**

```
setup(props, context) {
    watch(() => props.modelValue, (newValue, oldValue) => {
        console.log(newValue)
    })
}
```

Comment: you need t have an reference to your proxy. So the proxy can intercept if the property changes. with destructuring you assign your destructured property to an variable and you lose the reference

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`props` passed into `setup` is [reactive](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive) object and all reactivity is tight to the proxy around the object itself.

If you take a value of the property of such object, you get either:

1. Object (if the value is object), which is also reactive
2. Value (integer for example) which cannot be reactive by itself

And destructuring is just value assigment:

```js
const  { modelValue } = props
```

...is same as:

```js
const modelValue = props.modelValue
```

You can use `toRefs` as described in [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#props)

```js
export default {
    props: {
        modelValue: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },

    setup(props, context)
    {
        let { modelValue } = toRefs(props)

        watch(modelValue, (newValue, oldValue) => {
            console.log(newValue)
        })
    },
}
```

Now `modelValue` is [ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html) so it can be passed as first argument of `watch` (no need to for a function) and in most places you must use `modelValue.Value` to get it's value

Comment: Ooh, you saved my life! Thank you, I didn't know I needed to convert props to refs like that.

Comment: Well you don't **need** to if you pass `props` object around as a whole. But its necessary if you want to split the object into smaller parts and keep the "parts" reactive (same applies to any `reactive` object)

Answer (score 5):

Destructuring the `props` will cause the value to lose reactivity. (vue/no-setup-props-destructure)
[image]

[link to the docs rule](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-setup-props-destructure.html)

So what you can do instead is use destructuring in the `watch` like so:

```
watch(() => {
  const { modelValue } = props;
  console.log(modelValue);
});
```