# Props watch not working in Vue composition api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a `state` object being passed through as a prop from another component. I receive the `state` as expected. I then store the `props` in a `toRef()` for reactivity.

What I want to happen is when the data in `state` changes, I want to data in the browser to update. As it is right now, the data does get updated in the vue dev tools and I do see the `state` object change but the browser does not reflect the changes until I manually refresh the browser, which is an undesired result.

Why is this happening:

Component:

```html
<template>
      <div class="show-products">
        <Product
            v-for="data in products"
            :key="data.id"
            :product="data"
        />
      </div>
 </template>

<script>
import {computed, onMounted, toRefs, watch } from "vue";
import {useStore} from "vuex";
    
    export default {
      components: {Product},
      props: {
        state: Object
      },
      setup (props) {
        const store = useStore();
        const products = computed(() => store.getters.getProducts);
    
        let stateRef = toRefs(props).state;
    
        onMounted(() => {
          store.dispatch('getProducts');
        });
    
        watch(stateRef, (currentState, prevState) => {
          if (currentState.length !== prevState.length) {
            store.dispatch('getProducts');
          }
        })
    
        return {
          Product,
          products,
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: maybe you could specify your props like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926354/vue-3-watch-doesn-t-work-if-i-watch-a-destructured-prop)

Comment: Don't set it to a ref and then watch the ref. Watch the prop directly like the above solution suggests.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Observing the array length requires a deep watcher, so make sure to set the `deep` flag:

```js
watch(stateRef, (currentState, prevState) => {/*...*/}, { deep: true })
```

Also, the watcher callback only receives the data references, so if you're only mutating the original array (e.g., via `push()` or `pop()`), the `currentState` and `prevState` arguments will be the same reference, which would defeat the length check for differences.

A potential solution is to remove the length check, and always dispatch the `getProducts` action in the watcher:

```js
// ProductList.vue
watch(stateRef, (currentState, prevState) => {
  store.dispatch('getProducts')
}, { deep: true })
```

Another solution that does not require a deep watcher is to assign a new array to state instead of using `push()`/`pop()` on the original array:

```js
// Parent.vue
addState(newValue) {
  state.value = [ ...state.value, newValue ]
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-array-watcher?file=src/components/ProductList.vue)