# Vue 2 composition API watching the store

Tags: vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I have a store which is just an array of strings.
I am trying to watch it and do a search when it has changed.
Originally I had a computed value a bit like this:

```
const { value } = computed(() => {
  const urls = store.getters.wishlist;
  filters.value = createFilters("IndexUrl", urls);
  return useListProducts(page.value, filters.value);
});
```

which I returned like this:

```
return { ...value, skip, more };
```

This worked fine when loading the page the first time, but if another component adds/removes something from the wishlist I want the function to fire again.
For context, here is the whole component:

```
import {
  computed,
  defineComponent,
  getCurrentInstance,
  ref,
} from "@vue/composition-api";

import Product from "@components/product/product.component.vue";
import {
  createFilters,
  createRequest,
  useListProducts,
} from "@/_shared/logic/list-products";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Wishlist",
  components: { Product },
  setup() {
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();
    const store = instance.proxy.$store;
    const page = ref(1);
    const skip = ref(0);
    const filters = ref([]);

    const { value } = computed(() => {
      const urls = store.getters.wishlist;
      filters.value = createFilters("IndexUrl", urls);
      return useListProducts(page.value, filters.value);
    });

    const more = () => {
      skip.value += 12;
      page.value += 1;

      const request = createRequest(page.value, filters.value);

      value.fetchMore({
        variables: { search: request },
        updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
          if (!fetchMoreResult) return prev;

          return {
            search: {
              __typename: prev.search.__typename,
              hasMoreResults: fetchMoreResult.search.hasMoreResults,
              total: fetchMoreResult.search.total,
              facets: [...prev.search.facets, ...fetchMoreResult.search.facets],
              items: [...prev.search.items, ...fetchMoreResult.search.items],
            },
          };
        },
      });
    };

    return { ...value, skip, more };
  },
});
```

So I figured that the issue was that I wasn't actually watching anything, so I removed the **computed** method and instead decided to setup a watch. First I created a **listProducts** method:

```
const result = reactive({
  result: null,
  loading: null,
  error: null,
  fetchMore: null,
});

const listProducts = (urls: string[]) => {
  console.log(urls);
  filters.value = createFilters("IndexUrl", urls);
  Object.assign(result, useListProducts(page.value, filters.value));
};
```

And then I invoked that in my setup:

```
listProducts(store.getters.wishlist);
```

Then I setup a watch:

```
watch(store.getters.wishlist, (urls: string[]) => listProducts(urls));
```

What I expected to happen, was that when an item was added/remove from the wishlist store, it would then invoke **listProducts** with the new set of **urls**. But it didn't fire at all.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with destructuring the reactive property, on destructuring you assign the properties to variables and no longer have a proxy to react to changes..try

```
   return { value, skip, more };
```

and reference the property in your template

```
<template>
{{value.foo}}
</template
```

this question has to do with setup props but the same concept applies
[Vue 3 watch doesn’t work if I watch a destructured prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926354/vue-3-watch-doesn-t-work-if-i-watch-a-destructured-prop)

Comment: I don't understand. I have tried that and many other ways and it's not working. Should I be using my first bit of code or the second?